# Which type of argument passes a value to a procedure from the calling environment

Tags: mysql, sql, database, plsql, parameters

Which type of argument passes a value to a procedure from the calling environment
1.IN
2.IN OUT
3.OUT
4.OUT IN

If more than one answer is possible than give the answer.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: check my updated answer and accept it if it answers your query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for mysql stored procedure parameters modes not arguments as you mentioned wrongly in you question.

Parameters are the variables in method definition; arguments is the data which you pass to the functions or methods and parameters mode specify the context of the parameter.

Following are the mysql stored procedure parameters mode.

> 1. IN – It is the default mode. When you define an IN parameter in a stored procedure, the calling program has to pass an argument to the stored procedure
> 2. OUT – the value of an OUT parameter can be changed inside the stored procedure and its new value is passed back to the calling program.
> 3. INOUT – an INOUT  parameter is the combination of IN  and OUT  parameters. It means that the calling program may pass the argument, and the stored procedure can modify the INOUT parameter and pass the new value back to the calling program.

Source: [mysqltutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx)

**EXAMPLE** : To view only specific policy record from Policy table.

```
delimiter ##

create procedure view_policy(IN pid)
begin
     select * from Policy where policy_id=pid;
end##

delimiter ;
```

**UPDATE**

According to [mysql 5.7 reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) there is nothing called as "OUT IN"